# How to automatically schedule the execution of a function in the future?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I need a function in my contract to be executed daily by itself. 
I know that Ethereum Alarm Clock and Oraclize do it but none of them worked for me.

For example this code using Oraclize

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;    

import "http://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI_0.4.sol";

contract MyContract is usingOraclize {

    uint public tmp = 0;
    function callThisToStart() {
        oraclize_query(60, "URL", "");
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
        if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
        doSomething();
        callThisToStart();
    }

    function doSomething() {
        tmp++;
    }

}
```

I do not really know why it does not work (tmp is not increased)
I do not care about using EAC or Oraclize, but I really want to get that for example every minute the value of a variable increases

Thank you.

Comment: You need to be more detailed with your question, include code, and explain why Ethereum Alarm Clock and Oraclize didn't work. Please refer to [How To Ask A Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, its my first time.

Comment: to get started, try commenting out the `callThisToStart();` call from within the `__callback` function and check if that works: in order for this to work, you need to have funds available in the contract as the first oraclize call is the only free one - alternatively just comment the last line of your callback function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not necessary to use Ethereum Alarm Clock and Oraclize if you just want to execute a function.

Lets get down to basic. **What is a function?**

> A function is a type of procedure or routine. In solidity, you call a function to modify some state variables. And you can know that a state has been modified when you get the value of that variable.

Whichever variable you want to modify, you need not use it as a variable. Instead, you can declare that variable as a function, which returns the value on time variables of the blockchain, example, `blockNumber`, `block.timestamp`.

For answering your question, you can do the above described process by the contract given below.

This contract increases the value returned by `tmp` every minute. And there are separate functions to enable and disable this feature.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;    

contract MyContract {

    uint startTime;
    function tmp() public view returns(uint){
        require(startTime != 0);
        return (now - startTime)/(1 minutes);
    }
    function callThisToStart() {
        startTime = now;
    }
    function callThisToStop() {
        startTime = 0;
    }
    function doSomething() returns (uint){
        return tmp();
    }

}
```

Comment: Really love the clever coding here and works for this particular situation...however, if he actually needed the functionality to actually execute a function at a scheduled time, this wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes. The core idea of my answer is to make the contract such that it can run the scheduled txn itself.

Comment: I noticed. It's really clever. Definitely adding this to my arsenal! Thanks for this.

Comment: Sorry for being dumb here, but I can't see how is it that doSomething() has been executed by contract itself? Without actual call of doSomething()

Comment: same here @KwahuNashoba, what if I want my function to just run in exactly one hour without manually going and doing it myself. I checked Ethereum Alarm Clock which does this service but I am unsure whether its active and running or not

Comment: How is this _scheduling_ anything? doSomething has to be called by something else, and then it just _lazily_ calculates and returns the number of minutes since start time, and it's not even a transaction...